# Ajax Page load, gone when refresh page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

**I was working with Ajax now and I have this piece of code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(file,container)
       {
var xmlhttp, newhash = '';

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
if (window.ActiveXObject) {  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function (){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {  document.getElementById(container).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(container).innerHTML='<div style="padding:10px">       <p>Please upgrade your web browser to support modern technology.</p></div>';
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET",file,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="load('home.php','ajax');return false;">Home</a><li/>
</ul>
       <div id="ajax">



</div>
```

Sorry it's my first post but my real concern is that, the page can be loaded but then when I refresh the page the page  will just gone,. I tried to put a hash on the url but then it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is problem? I checked your code and it is working fine.

Comment: If you already use jquery you can do this much easier and cleaner with jquery load http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I will check it @hsalama..thanks for your feedback!!!! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your content is being loaded only on the button click. You'll need to tell the browser to auto-load* the content depending on your hash.

For this, you can:

1 - Give a hash to your link, by specifying it in the `href` attrbiute. Remove the `return false;` from your `onclick` to ensure the page url changes to `#home`

```
<a href="#home" onclick="load('home.php','ajax');">Home</a>
```

2 - Add an `onload` handler that auto-loads the page specified in the hash.

```
<body onload="loadHash();">
```

3 - Write the auto hash loader

```
<script>
function loadHash() {
    var hash = window.location.href.split('#');
    if(hash.length == 2) {
        load(hash[1] + '.php','ajax');
    }
}
</script>
```